# ephelcystic nu of contract verbal forms in Ancient Greek

Tags: verbs, greek, conjugation

Since some verbal forms may have an ephelcystic nu (imperfect.3S : ἐπαίδευε/ἐπαίδευεν), I would like to know if [un/]contract forms too may have this ending, as if we had ἐτίμαεν instead of ἐτίμαε and ἐτίμᾱν instead of ἐτίμᾱ.

ἐτίμαεν seems (?) ok to me but I can't remember having read contract forms like "ἐτίμᾱν" but, if so, I would like to understand why they [doesn't] exist. Is the ephelcystic nu linked to the sounds -ε or -ι ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smyth (134b) says: "Verbs in -εω never (in Attic) add -ν to the 3 sing. of the *contracted* form: εὖ ἐποίει αὐτόν *he treated him well*. But ᾔει *went* and pluperfects (as ᾔδει *knew*) may add ν." It can, however, appear in uncontracted forms: Herodotus has e.g. ἐδόκεεν, ἐκόσμεεν, etc.